# Writing to txt file creates unwanted first column

Tags: r, export, dataframe

I have this `data frame` called "`Datos`" (summary):

`Datos[1:10,1:5]`:

```
 RUN_ADM                                        NOM_ADM RUN_FM Tipo.de.Fondo.Mutuo FECHA_INF
1  96767630 BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.   8001                   5  19860902
2  96767630 BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.   8001                   5  19860903
3  96767630 BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.   8001                   5  19860904
4  96767630 BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.   8001                   5  19860905
5  96767630 BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.   8001                   5  19860906
6  96767630 BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.   8001                   5  19860907
7  96767630 BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.   8001                   5  19860908
8  96767630 BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.   8001                   5  19860909
9  96767630 BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.   8001                   5  19860910
10 96767630 BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.   8001                   5  19860911
```

Where Datos[1:10,1] (`$RUN_ADM`):

```
[1] 96767630 96767630 96767630 96767630 96767630 96767630 96767630 96767630 96767630 96767630
```

Then I `subset`:

```
  Datos2<-subset(Datos,Datos[,4]==5)
```

And then write into txt file:

```
write.table(Datos2,"C:/Users/Tomas/Desktop/Memoria de Titulo/CartolaTipo5.txt", sep="\t",col.names = TRUE)
```

The thing is that this produces a file with a new column ( the first one ) sort of an ID key. And the colnames are displace:

```
RUN_ADM NOM_ADM RUN_FM  Tipo.de.Fondo.Mutuo FECHA_INF
1   96767630    BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.  8001    5
2   96767630    BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.  8001    5
3   96767630    BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.  8001    5
4   96767630    BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.  8001    5
5   96767630    BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.  8001    5
6   96767630    BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.  8001    5
7   96767630    BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.  8001    5
8   96767630    BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.  8001    5
9   96767630    BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.  8001    5
10  96767630    BANCHILE ADMINISTRADORA GENERAL DE FONDOS S.A.  8001    5
```

Now my first column "RUN_ADM" is:

```
RUN_ADM
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

What do I have to do to avoid this first new column ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are the rownames. To not include rownames set `row.names = FALSE` in the call to `write.table`

```
write.table(Datos2,"C:/Users/Tomas/Desktop/Memoria de Titulo/CartolaTipo5.txt", 
            sep="\t",col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
```